# Is there a book that covers the period between first contact and the creation of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu, first-contact

In the *Star Trek* universe, why and how did humanity change from the time of first contact with the Vulcans to the creation of *Starfleet*?  Is there a book that covers this time period?

The basis of the *Star Trek* universe is that humanity did away with things like poverty, racism, starvation... all the terrible things we have today.  It has been said many times that the catalyst was the first contact, when humanity met aliens for the first time and realized they were not alone in the universe.

I just want to know if this time period was ever discussed in detail in a book.  Other than it just being mentioned.

Comment: Why: because entropy. How: all sorts of ways. Probably Q in there somewhere. Probably Wesley too. You are asking two distinct questions- one is that you want a rundown of the history of the universe over the course of literally hundreds of years and several TV series. That is so very broad that I don't know that it could reasonably be answered to any objectively satisfactory level. Your second question is asking for a book or source that will tell you the answer to the first question.

Comment: @Broklynite As the OP lists "the time of first contact" first followed by "the creation of starfleet", I suspect that "first contact" means the first contact between the people of Earth and an alien race, not the film called "Star Trek: First Contact".

Comment: @Broklynite - What does entropy have to do with humanity becoming *more* organized between the time of first contact and the creation of starfleet? Also, "over the course of literally hundreds of years" is wrong, first contact with the Vulcans happened in 2063, and the first season of *Enterprise* was set in 2151, when the [first starship Enterprise](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Enterprise_(NX-01)) was already part of the [United Earth Starfleet](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet#United_Earth_Starfleet) which existed before the Federation was formed in 2161.

Comment: The title spells out First Contact with caps, indicating to me at least the movie where the Enterprise traveled back in time, to the formation of star fleet and then First Contact "present" time. If that's unreasonable of me, then I'm sorry. And @Hypnosifl one of the questions was why humanity changed. There are many reasons. Entropy is absolutely one of them. If you don't see that, then you don't understand how entropy works, and the comments section is not a place for explaining the laws of thermodynamics in detail. The question is still ridiculous in scope.

Comment: @Broklynite It's a common practice to capitalize all the 'important' words in a title and not the function words. Since the title is not in the form of a proper English question, it's hard to say which first contact the OP is thinking of.

Comment: Isn’t this too broad? The question basically wants us to summarize humanity’s history between 2063 and 2120 or so. I’m sure there must have been oodles written about that in the *Star Trek* expanded universe.

Comment: @Adamant: “The question basically wants us to summarize humanity’s history between 2063 and 2120 or so. I’m sure there must have been oodles written about that in the *Star Trek* expanded universe.” Don’t be so sure! This isn’t Star Wars.

Comment: I edited the title in accordance with this part of your question: “I just want to know if this time period was ever discussed in detail in a book.  Other than it just being mentioned.”